# How does OpenCV imread convert between 16 bit and 8 bit

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently dealing with depth images retrieved from a kinect sensor that have been saved as 16 bit grayscale PNG's. At the moment I'm just loading these images using the `imread()` function with the `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` flag and everything works fine. The reason why I'm doing this is because some OpenCV functions rely on the input being **8 bit**.

Here is the problem: The next step is to use the depth frames captured by the sensor, which come as 16 bit, directly. I though it would be sufficient to scale and convert the values using `covertTo(dst, CV_8U, 1.0/256.0)` but for some reason the resulting image looks very different from the ones loaded as 8 bit? So, how does OpenCV convert the image when loaded as 8 bit.

Here is the [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-qt8lafqDaeTld4SkJjYWJpQ1k/view?usp=sharing) I used for a test and here is some code that shows the problem:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    Mat depth8 = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat depth16 = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);

    depth16.convertTo(depth16, CV_8U, 1.0/256.0);

    Mat diff;
    absdiff(depth8, depth16, diff);

    //imshow("depth8", depth8*255.0/16.0);
    //imshow("depth16", depth16*255.0/16.0);
    imshow("diff", diff > 0);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-qt8lafqDaeWF9iQ2RydEgtVE0/view?usp=sharing).

I case you wonder why the test image is so dark, it is because the maximum value for 16 bit is so much larger than the values produced by kinect (up to around 4000).

Another thing: The image loaded as 8 bit seems to be much better than the converted one. If you comment in the two lines you can see what I mean.

So again: How is OpenCV doing its conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably just grabbing the 8 most significant bits from the 16-bit value.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I tested it and they really are just grabbing the bits. That's strange because whenever a user wants to convert between types they are applying a saturate_cast<>. In the documentation they say that they are doing this "to not just form the result by taking some bits of the input".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the `imread` function will eventually call `imread_(...)` in `highgui/src/loadsave.cpp`.
2. the correct decoder will be determined in `imread_` function and a matrix `mat` was initialized according to the second parameter in `imread()`.
3. `mat` is passed to the `readData()` method of the decoder. In this case, a png decoder is invoked.
4. Depending on the depth of `mat`, `png_set_strip_16` in the png decoder (`highgui/src/grfmt_png.cpp`) might be called.
5. `png_set_strip_16()` makes libpng to call `png_do_chop()` eventually. (It simply discard the low byte. see `pngrtran.c` in libpng)